# Why does this table extend past the width of the window?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out what to do to make this work.  I just want to have the innermost div scrollable, but for some reason the width extends past the window.

```
<table style='max-height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; border: 0px none white; display: block;'>
    <tr style='border: 0px none white; width: 100%;'>
        <td style='border: 0px none white; width: 100%;'>
            <div style='overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%;'>
                <div style='padding-left: 5px; width: 100%;'>
                    <div style='overflow: auto; width: 100%; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid silver; background-color: transparent;'>
                        <p>kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGEkU/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `display:block` from the table (otherwise you might as well use a `<div>`), and add
`table-layout:fixed`. This forces the table to the width you say, instead of treating it as "min-width"

Comment: Ugh, I've been beating my head against a wall for a long time for this.  The "display: block" I added just while I was trying different things out.  Looks like I'll have to research table-layout to figure out "why" it works.  But it does work.  I'll accept your answer when I can.

Comment: Old standards say that table cells should use the width if possible, but stretch if the content requires it. `table-layout:fixed` makes it obey the width, even if it means the content won't fit.